# How to use @Contains with @Implode in Lotus Formula

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I have a document item called Pathname which is Text List containing paths to databases. I need to create a view, with only specific documents, which contain a specific database path in Pathname item. 
I have tried these statements but none has worked:

1.*@isMember("Databasepath",Pathname)*

2.*@Contains(@Implode(Pathname);"Databasepath")*

Thank You for any suggestion.

Comment: It's been a while, but I seem to recall that `@Contains` can directly accept text lists as arguments. Note that it is case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for the "implode" in your code.

If Pathname looks like this:

`apps\database1.nsf; apps\database2.nsf; mail\mailfile1.nsf;`

and you want to filter out all in "apps" path, then the formula would look like this:

```
@Contains( PathName; "apps\\" )
```

Don't forget to duplicate the backslashes, if you "hardcode" them, as they are escape characters.

But now think about a Pathname containing:

`localapps\db1.nsf; apps\db2.nsf; local\apps\db3.nsf`

Then the formula above would select ALL entries. In that case this formula would be better:

```
@Contains( "#" + PathName; "#apps\\" )
```

Or (if the given path is always at the beginning):

```
@Begins( PathName; "apps\\" )
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's truly a text list (i.e., "Path1\Db1.nsf" : "Path2\Db2.nsf" : "Path3\Db3.nsf"), then you should just be able to use the equals operator because a comparison of a scalar to a list value returns true if the scalar matches any of the list values. This detail of the semantics of formula language actually makes a lot of uses of @Contains unnecessary!

I.e., it should be as simple as

```
SELECT Pathname = "Path1\\Db1.nsf";
```

or if Pathname is not already case normalized, then

```
SELECT @uppercase(Pathname) = "PATH1\\DB1.NSF";
```